# CentOS 6.5 R Installation Dependencies

Tags: linux, r, centos, rpm, epel

## Update:

Please note that I did post a different flavor of this on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160582/31688), but received no helpful responses in the day before re-posting here. The information from that post that is relevant here is that I first added EPEL 7 to the list of repos using `rpm -Uvh` which is probably why the EL 7 version of R is being requested.

Anyway, as requested by user Sami Laine, here is the output from `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

And the output from  `rpm -q epel-release` is `epel-release-6-8.noarch`.

---

I am trying to install R on a fresh CentOS 6.5 box, but am running into difficulties with dependencies. I added the EPEL 6 repo using `rpm`, and then ran a `yum install R`. It aborted with broken dependencies:

```
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.1.1-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.5()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libquadmath.so.0()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package R-java.x86_64 0:3.1.1-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-headless for package: R-java-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package texlive-texmf-errata-fonts.noarch 0:2007-7.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libquadmath.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-java-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-headless
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Not sure why these dependencies are not getting resolved. Also any reason why **el7** version is being installed when my CentOS is 6.5?

Comment: Hmmm that's strange, I just did this yesterday on the exact same system (CentOS 6.5) without issue. Do you have `Development tools` installed already (`yum groupinstall 'Development tools'`)?

Comment: @nrussell Yes, I did that prior to this.

Comment: @SamiLaine I have created a chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62909/centos-6-5-r-installation-dependencies) in case you would like to join.

Comment: @SamiLaine Thanks, that works! Although it did tell me that there is no such thing as `yum refresh`. Please put your comments in an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since EPEL release 7 has been installed (and then removed), some of metadata used by dependency chain checking contains conflicting residue from that. Though you have installed EPEL release 6, the metadata is still left there to bother.

To clean metadata and generate it again, run:

```
yum clean all && yum makecache
```